# MySQL- Truncating Date-Time in a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select * from player_source 
where source is not null
```

which results in

```
ID      create_dtime
001     2012-10-16 16:13:27
002     2012-12-10 16:13:27
```

and so on...

I want to filter the query so that it only returns results with a create_dtime greater than or equal to december 3 2012 , and less than or equal to december 9 2012.

I tried using

```
select * from player_source 
where source is not null
and Create_Dtime >= To_Date('2012-Dec-03','yyyy-mon-dd')
and Create_Dtime <= To_Date('2012-Dec-09','yyyy-mon-dd')
```

using my Oracle roots, but it didn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
select * 
from player_source 
where source is not null
and Create_Dtime >= '2012-10-03'
and Create_Dtime <= '2012-10-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select * 
 from player_source 
 where source is not null
 and Create_Dtime >= '2012-Dec-03'
 and Create_Dtime <= '2012-Dec-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
select * from player_source 
where source is not null
and Create_Dtime > '2012-12-03'
and Create_Dtime <= '2012-12-09'
```

or, more succinctly:

```
select * from player_source 
where source is not null
and Create_Dtime > '2012-12-03' BETWEEN
and '2012-12-09'
```